# Spark read CSV realtive path

Tags: csv, apache-spark, relative-path

How can I read a CSV into spark using a relative path?
So far using an absolute path worked just fine (1.6.2, 2.0.1) but I would require loading of the data via a relative path.

Trying to read the file like

```
val mynewDf = spark.read
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("charset", "UTF-8")
    .option("delimiter", ";")
    .csv("~/myProject/someFolder/data.csv")
```

Results in the following exception

```
Path does not exist: file:/Users/geoHeil/source/to/scala/sparkProject/~/myProject/someFolder/data.csv;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So not always it is spark to be blamed ;) I settled on using plain scala to get the relative file path:

```
var path = "~/myProject/data/data.csv"
path = path.replaceFirst("^~", System.getProperty("user.home"))
```